# Issue connecting Linux Jenkins master from Windows slave

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins

I have Linux jenkins master server and windows slave and trying to add windows slave to master. But it try connecting linuxhost:49187 (here we are trying connect using Java web start)

Is there any configuration change need to be done on Linux master to connect to windows slave?

Comment: Did you add the slave in jenkins master from UI ?

Comment: try adding it from console , but when I launch slave agent from windows box it's not getting connected